# Is there a way of unit test click event on an ag grid cellRendererSelector

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to test some behavior in an angular ag-grid. The internal component in the column is being defined with a `cellRendererSelector` attribute to either render a link component or a normal container (well not normal, it defines a tooltip for when the cell content is too big).

As for now I have found no way of testing the click event in that cell, i.e. testing that the link triggers the navigation.

Does anyone have experience with such case?

Any help appreciated

Comment: do you need cellRendererSelector click event ?

Answer (score 0):

```
cellEditorSelector : (params:any) => {
        if (params.colDef.colId === 'amount') {
          return {
            component: NumericCellEditor,
          }
        }
        return undefined
      }


this is a numeric component code : 

agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
}
```

you can debugger in agInit funtion and you can check your unit test

agInit is default function of cellEditor